# Can "fornicate" be used as a transitive verb?

Tags: verbs, offensive-language, euphemisms, transitivity

(I’m asking this for someone else who doesn’t know about this site (yet).)

Could *fornicate* be used as a transitive verb, as in

> We have to keep A from fornicating B.

I don’t believe it can.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, MikeBaz. Did you look up "fornicate"? What did the dictionary say about its transitivity?

Comment: I did look it up and saw two different answers, hence my question. MW says yes: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fornicate while others say no: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fornicate   Because I can't ask MW in particular why they are different this seemed better. Sorry if I offended your sensitivities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My dictionaries all list it as intransitive. The usual term is *fornicating with someone*, not *fornicating someone*.

That said, feel free to use it anyway you like. "Fornicate you" would be understood as a euphemism (barely) for "fuck you."

Answer (score 2):

Houghton-Mifflin and Collins both list it as an intransitive verb. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fornicate I'd say the answer appears to be "no".

On the other hand, if you used it transitively, I think your meaning would be clear, so it wouldn't be a bad usage to coin.

Comment: Oh, Robusto's point that saying "with X" probably makes the value of coining a new usage unnecessary.